# How to correct missing cells / missing delimiters causing "shifted" data in sets of columns?

Tags: python, ruby, excel, vba, openrefine

I have per-row semicolon separated manufacturer products and vendor data which has missing cells.
The spreadsheet has multiple vendors for each manufacturers product.

The order of the data will always be the same columnwise:

```
vendor_name_1, vendor_address_1, vendor_phone_1, vendor_fax_1, vendor_contact_mobile_1, vendor_contact_email_1, etc.
```

When there is more than one vendor for that product (almost all most do), there is another repeat of the columns in the same order left to right:

```
vendor_name_2, vendor_address_2, vendor_phone_2, vendor_fax_2, vendor_contact_mobile_2, vendor_contact_email_2, etc.
```

At this point the sets of columns repeat as long as there are more vendors for the product on that row.

A "good" row will have all of the available data in the correct column:

```
Motion Distributors; 3231 Apex Drive; Dulles, Ohio 45321; (321) 542-6422(p); (321) 542-6428(f); (321) 542-6680(m); alan@motiondist.com; etc. etc.
```

A "bad" row will have one or more missing items for at least one vendor on the row, which of course effects everything to the right of that missing cell, so everything is shifted.

Since some of the data in the cells are missing, the  issue is getting the data in each row back to the correct cell.

For example, if the vendor_fax number is missing, all of the cells to the right of that missing cell do not go into the correct column and are shifted.

To make things worse, because there are multiple vendors for the same product, the more missing cells per row, the more shifting occurs on that row.

Is there a way to fix this since each column set has the same arrangement and only the extra delimiters are missing?

I am hoping there is a fix at least for company and contact names and the phone numbers by a generic match of each column type (name, phone number, email, etc.)?

Is there a way to process the spreadsheet by each row to ensure the matches occur?  If necessary, I can split cells into other columns if it will allow for more specific matching.

I am desperate enough to go with any language or utility necessary to solve the problem.

I have searched through several categories here on SO and am not seeing a way to solve this (yet)...

Comment: I will follow up on this post after I have a working solution so others can solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the format of things like phone numbers is predictable and easy to discern (i.e the difference between the phone and fax is obvious as in your example) then it should be fairly easy to take a good guess at how fields match.
I would create a hash of Regex's something like:

```
field_regexes = { 
  name:    \^.+$\,
  street:  \^d+\s\,
  city:    \^.*,\s\d{5}$\,
  phone:   \^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\-\d{4}\(p\)$\, 
  fax:     \^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\-\d{4}\(f\)$\, 
  mobile:  \^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\-\d{4}\(m\)$\, 
  email:   \^\w+\@\w+.\w+$\,
  etc... 
}
```

The code might be something like:

```
fields = input.split(';').map(&:strip)

while fields.present? do
  record = parse_record(fields) 
  break unless record.present?  # something went wrong
  save(record) 
end

def parse_record(fields)
  result = {}

  field_regexes.each do |name, regex| do
    if fields[0] =~ regex
      result[name] = fields.unshift
      break if fields.empty?
    end
  end

  result
end
```

Note: This assumes that there are no colons that should be considered valid data (A colon in an address or company name for example)

Comment: Wow thank you very much for taking the time to provide such an explicit solution!

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution would be to have whoever is sending you this data spit out a delimiter even for blank columns, then all your columns would line up on import with no problem. Assuming that getting your input fixed isn't an option...

I think you'll need to identify what data is in each column of your input on a column-by-column basis

Email addresses are easy - there is an `@` and a `.` in them or they're not valid. If you find one that's in the wrong place, shift right until it's in the email column.

Missing phone numbers are pretty easy too. Since they seem to have `(p)`, `(f)` and `(m)` to identify the number type, simply pull the last three characters to identify which number you have. If you're missing one, shift the remainder to the right until the one you have is in the correct column.

Identifying a zip code is fairly straight forward, it's either 5 `02134` or 9 digits `021345678` or, possibly 10 characters `02134-5678`. Shift right until it lines up.

If states are spelled out, have a table listing all the states, and if you find a match earlier than expected, shift right until the state is in the right place. If states are the standard 2-character postal abbreviations, just look for a 2-character column and shift right until it matches.

US street addresses *should* start with a house (or building) number, so a character string beginning with a digit *should* be an address, but it could possibly be a zip-code (zip+4 with the embedded dash `-`), so if it's all numeric (possibly including the dash), then that's the zip field, otherwise it's an address field.

The city... well that's an all alpha field that should be what's left after sorting out all the rest.

The company name - all this presumes the company name is actually there to begin the record, if not, you might be a bit out of luck, but I'm sure there's some way to identify what's there.

You might want to try something like a state machine. I'm at this point in the record, so here's what I *expect* to find next, let's look at the next column of data to see what's *actually* there, and shift right until it seems to line up. That should minimize the error for a missing company name or city name misidentification.

You should be able to write that in the language of your choice, but it may not be the fastest thing in the world, since it will have to do the import one field at a time.

Comment: I examined some of Google Refine capability but noticed I could not get to a second level of nesting (I may be using the wrong term).  I am looking at datamystic text pipe pro now to achieve the per-row incomplete cell analyzing logic in Perl now...